# How to Generate a Custom Serial Numbers by Branch and Year In Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to Generate a Custom Serial Numbers(Auto Increment) by Branch and Year In  Entity Framework Code First
If I add a new record and change the branch or year it generates a new serial number automatically

I Need Add attributes To This Model

```
public class Stock
    {
        public Guid ID { set; get; }
        public Int64 SerialNo { set; get; }
        public int Year { set; get; }
        public string Baranch { set; get; }

        public string Item { set; get; }
        public decimal Price { set; get; }
    }
```

Output Like This

```
|                 _ID_               |_SerialNo_|_Year_|_Branch_|_Item_|_Price_|
|97A7A400-B6AB-4AB2-AF0C-0280641223A1|    1     | 2018 |Main    |Corola|250$   |
|1ED15B3E-2B7D-400B-8098-EEDD50C121E3|    2     | 2018 |Main    |Camry |750$   |
|4A06A5AF-8BF7-4F43-9E1C-11B94BC56060|    3     | 2018 |Main    |Atoz  |100$   |
|3437E251-36B9-4967-B2C3-9DAFAD2B997A|    1     | 2017 |Main    |C7    |300$   |
|2F501488-89C7-4609-8BFF-5580A7A5A8CB|    2     | 2017 |Main    |Corola|720$   |
|09C9FF51-3ABC-436D-B3CF-67B71F7AAFD6|    3     | 2017 |Main    |GMC   |500$   |
|DA566E19-258D-4FB5-8B8F-9FCF102F98FC|    1     | 2015 |Bar2    |Other |450$   |
|727410AA-B420-427D-9ED5-7927DD269DFC|    2     | 2015 |Bar2    |C7    |300$   |
|228F599F-89D4-45C3-B6FE-8E236D07485D|    3     | 2015 |Bar2    |Corola|720$   |
|46ECFA2E-5252-4E4C-8A3B-7F067B37208E|    4     | 2015 |Bar2    |GMC   |500$   |
|79037BCE-4D18-458B-BF54-18BC2115697E|    1     | 2018 |Bar2    |Other |450$   |
|D75A18AF-48B4-404F-9D0F-997A14C4DE0E|    2     | 2018 |Bar2    |Other |450$   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Guid within your constructor like this:

```
public class Stock {
...
    public Stock() {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I want automatic increment for (serial_No) field 
By branch and year

if  i insert 
St=stock();
st.id=Guid.NewGuid():
st.Baranch ="A";
st.Year=2015;
db.Stock.add(st);
db.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine("serial="+st.Serial_No);

OutPut=> serial=1